# Insert a new line after every N lines?

Tags: text-processing

How can I use text-processing tools to insert a new line after every N lines?

Example for N=2:

INPUT:

```
sadf
asdf
yxcv
cxv
eqrt
asdf
```

OUTPUT:

```
sadf
asdf

yxcv
cxv

eqrt
asdf
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk ' {print;} NR % 2 == 0 { print ""; }' inputfile
```

With `sed` (`GNU` extension):

```
sed '0~2 a\\' inputfile
```

With `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
lines=0
while IFS= read -r line
do
    printf '%s\n' "${line}"
    ((lines++ % 2)) && echo
done < "$1"
```

Comment: Arithmetic evaluation can be used directly as condition, no need for the `[[ ]]` to test: `while read line; do echo "$line"; ((lines++ % 2)) && echo; done`.

Comment: Be aware that the above documented command `sed '0~2 a\ '` adds a space to each inserted newline. If you wanted to add a newline after each line, any of these similarly work: `sed '0~1 a\ '`, `sed 'a\ '`, or just `sed G`.

Answer (score 7):

## sed (GNU)

With (GNU) `sed`:

```
sed '0~2G'
```

Short (ugly for N=100):

```
sed 'n;G'
```

man sed explains ~ as:

> first ~ step
>   Match every step'th line starting with line first. For example, ``sed -n 1~2p'' will print all the odd-numbered lines in the input stream, and the address 2~5 will match every fifth line, starting with the second. first can be zero; in this case, sed operates as if it were equal to step. (This is an extension.)

## sed (other)

With other sed (Count new lines):

```
sed -e 'p;s/.*//;H;x;/\n\{2\}/{g;p};x;d'
```

Or, to be more portable, written as (remove comments for some versions of sed) :

```
sed -e '             # Start a sed script.
         p            # Whatever happens later, print the line.
         s/.*//       # Clean the pattern space.
         H            # Add **one** newline to hold space.
         x            # Get the hold space to examine it, now is empty.
         /\n\{2\}/{   # Test if there are 2 new lines counted.
             g        # Erase the newline count.
             p        # Print an additional new line.
           }          # End the test.
         x            # match the `x` done above.
         d            # don't print anything else. Re-start.
       '              # End sed script.
```

## awk

With `awk`, probably:

```
awk '1 ; NR%2==0 {printf"\n"} '
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `paste`

```
 paste -d'\n' - - /dev/null <file
```

Answer (score 5):

```
sed n\;G <infile
```

... is all you need ...

For example:

```
seq 6 | sed n\;G
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
1
2

3
4

5
6
```

...*(and a blank follows the 6 as well)*...or...

```
seq 5 | sed n\;G
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
1
2

3
4

5
```

*(and no blank follows the 5)*

If a blank should always be omitted in a last line case:

```
sed 'n;$!G' <infile
```

Answer (score 3):

Another awk flavour:

```
awk '{ l=$0; getline; printf("%s\n%s\n\n", l, $0) }'
```

Comment: "This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content." I'll accept it... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Using **Perl**

```
~$ perl -ne 'print $_; if ($. % 2 == 0) { print "\n"};'  file
```

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -ne '.put; if (++$ %% 2) { print "\n"};'  file
```

The Perl answer uses `$_` which is Perl's topic variable, and `$.` which is Perl's line-number variable. If the line number `%` modulo 2 equals zero, insert a `\n` newline.

The Raku answer uses `$_` but in an abbreviated form: `.put` is short for `$_.put`. The Raku answer uses `++$` an anonymous pre-incrementing counter variable. Raku's `%%` 'Divisibility operator' is set to return True if `++$ % 2 == 0`, so again (like the Perl answer), a `\n` newline is inserted.

Sample Input:

```
sadf
asdf
yxcv
cxv
eqrt
asdf
```

Sample Output:

```
sadf
asdf

yxcv
cxv

eqrt
asdf
```

---

*Perl References:*
https://perldoc.perl.org
https://www.perl.org

*Raku References:*
https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org